# Photos of particular place id

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-places-api

How I can get all the pictures of a particular "place_id"?

When I retrieve the list of "places" in a particular location I have only access to one particular image "photo_reference".

I want to show the details of place through its "places_id" (more specific search), but the result of the API function no associated picture appears. If you're looking through places that google places "id" concrete many more images appear. How I can recover them?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code and the url you're requesting? Just remove the api key from the url. Also an example place_id.

Comment: I 've noticed that the place had no pictures , on the other hand , if you have google maps image shows a default image of "street view" , it is possible to put that image not available if any ?

Comment: Do you have an example place_id you're talking about?

Comment: Yes, this is the url "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJ10KlwAdzXg0RsH56kZsfcHs&key=xxxxxxx"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the street view image API when the places API doesn't return any photos. You can use the coordinates you receive from the places response in the request to the street view API to a link something like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=46.414382,10.013988&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

You probably need to enable the street view api in the google developers console along with your places api.

Street view reference:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/?hl=en

Assuming you have an element with an id of `attributions` and an element with id of `image` you could do the following with the JavaScript API. Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adooRp

```
  var attributions = document.getElementById("attributions");   
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(attributions);

  var request = {
      placeId: 'ChIJ10KlwAdzXg0RsH56kZsfcHs'   
  };

  service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
          var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();

          var src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location="
+ lat + "," + lng + "&key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE";

          document.getElementById("image").src = src;

      }   
  });
```

Comment: Worth noting, this won't angle the street view frame towards the place, it'll just plonk the camera down at the lat/lng facing a random direction.